# Problem in proving fixed point theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, functional-inequalities

Let  $ f(x)=x^r, 1<r<\infty, x\in \mathbb{R^+}=[0,\infty) ~and ~n\in \mathbb{N}.$ Define
  $$\pi(x)= 1 ~~if~~ x\leq n ~and =0 ~if~ x< (n+1).$$ Then for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R},~~ $ I want to prove that
$$\|\pi(\|x\|_{L^r})x^r-\pi(\|y\|_{L^r})y^r\|_{L^1}\leq C\|x-y\|_{L^r}, $$
 where $C$ is constant and strictly less than $1.$

Can Any one help me to prove it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think we run into a problem with the $L^r$- norm when $|x|>1$ for large $r$. Can you verify if the domain for $x$ should be $x\in\mathbb{R}$? Also, is there any information about the case that $x=n$?

Comment: @Master Yoda , I think the equality sign is with $n$ , which I have edited now. And  here we have taken $L^1$ on left because we have $rth$ power inside the norm, which may manage the $L^r$ norm on the right side.

Comment: Or we can also take the cut off function as   .>  $\pi(x)=1 ~~if 0 \leq x\leq n,~~ =n+1-x ~~if n<y<n+1~~ and =0$  ~~otherwise for $x\in  \mathbb{R}^+.$